# tabular figure with subfloat with wrong image location

Tags: tables, tabularx, subfloats, subfig

I have a figure where I want the middle image be completely between the top and bottom borders however, it goes down:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}





\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subfloat[joint effort action]{%
            {\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
            }

& 

\multirow{2}{*}{\subfloat[State machine behavior sequence]{%
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.43\textwidth]{example-image}}
                    }
                    }

& 

\subfloat[end-effector wrench]{
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
                    } \\

\subfloat[joint position feedback]{%
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
                    }

&                    
& 

\subfloat[end-effector pose feedback]{%
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
                    }
\end{tabular}
 \label{fig:fifig}%
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it so that the (b) image is exactly in the middle of the upper and lower border?

Comment: @Mico does it run in overleaf? I don't mind if it's not very restrictive

Comment: @Mico so how do I make the same figure with LuaLaTeX

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I posted my initial comment below the wrong posting.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

With use of the `adjustbox` (for moving images baseline to their top) and `subcaption` packages (for aligning subfigures at top):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.22\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-a} 
\caption{joint effort action}
\end{subfigure}
    &   \multirow{2}[4]{*}{%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.55\linewidth}%
            \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image}
        \caption{State machine behavior sequence}
        \end{subfigure}}
        &   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\linewidth}%
                \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image}
            \caption{end-effector wrench}%
            \end{subfigure}     \\
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.22\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-b}
\caption{joint position feedback}
\end{subfigure}
    &   &   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.22\linewidth}%
                \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image}
            \caption{end-effector pose feedback}
            \end{subfigure}
\end{tabular}
\caption{my figures}
\label{fig:fifig}%
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```